# Right solution?

Tags: proof-verification

I am trying to solve an equation in the research article. $f(g)$ is the pdf below:

\begin{align}
f(g)  = \frac{(K+1)e^{-K}}{\bar g}exp\Bigg(-\frac{(K+1)g}{\bar g}\Bigg) I_o\Bigg(\sqrt\frac{4K(K+1)g}{\bar g}\Bigg)
\end{align}

$I_o(.)$ is the zeroth order modified Bessel Function of the first kind.

and $\bar g = K+1$.

Here is the complete derivation I have done (following authors hints, since research paper do not solve all the problems):

$$f(g)  = e^{-K-g} I_o(\sqrt{4Kg})$$

Now, since $I_n(x)$ has a series representation as:

$$I_n(x) =  \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{n+2k}}{(n+k)!\; k!} $$

So for $I_o(.)$, we get

$$ I_o(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$$

Hence finally I got $$ f(g) = e^{-K-g} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(Kg)^k}{(k!)^2} $$

Since $f(g)$ is the pdf, the CDF would be $F_{f(g)}(g)$. Now I do not understand and could not solve beyond this. Author says that the CDF can be simplified by applying 2.321.2 from the following image (reference: **Table of Integrals, Series, and Products**):

[image]

The result that author has yield is :

$$ F_{f(g)}(g) = e^{-K}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{K^k}{k!} \Bigg\{e^{-g}\sum_{m=0}^k(-1)^{2m+1}m! \binom{m}{k} x^{k-m} + k!\Bigg\}$$

I really cannot understand how he came up to this !!! Any idea?

Comment: Your series for $I_0(x)$ is wrong.  It should be $$\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2k}}{(k!)^2}$$

Comment: yes, it was a typo. corrected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the density

$$f(g) = e^{-K-g} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{K^k g^k}{(k!)^2}\ \text{for}\ g > 0  $$
(the $g>0$ is a detail you left out, but it's important).

For the CDF, you integrate term-by-term: for $x > 0$

$$\eqalign{F(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \int_0^x e^{-K-g} \frac{K^k g^k}{(k!)^2} \; dg\cr
&= e^{-K} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{K^k}{(k!)^2} \sum_{j=0}^k - j! \left. {k \choose j} e^{-g} g^{k-j}\right|_{g=0}^x\cr
}$$
Note that ${k\choose j} = \frac{k!}{j!(k-j)!}$ and $\left. e^{-g} g^{k-j}\right|_{g=0}^x = e^{-x} x^{k-j}$ for $j < k$ but $e^{-x} - 1$ for $j=k$.
Thus the result becomes

(EDITED)

$$ F(x) = 1 - e^{-K-x} \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{K^k}{k!} \sum_{j=0}^k \frac{x^{k-j}}{(k-j)!}$$

I don't know where that $K^{k^2}$ comes from: it must be a typo.

Comment: yes, $K^{k^2}$ is the typo, but still, your answer does not match the answer that I posted for the author's result. I myself am unable to get that result, and yours as well...The values are nearly equal, but not the same.


But still, many thanks for your time. :)

Comment: Actually, I learned about the typo by reading another paper from the same authors which leads to this paper. But still, the other results are the same in this paper as well.

Comment: Shouldn't because of $\left. e^{-g} g^{k-j}\right|_{g=0}^x = e^{-x} x^{k-j}$ for $j < k$ but $e^{-x} - 1$ for $j=k$., it should be $[e^{-g}g^{k-j} + e^{-g} - 1]\times A$ ? where A is the rest of the math? I have tried it a thousand times...Could not come to the final conclusion...

Comment: Extremely sorry for the late response on this, you might thing the matter is solve... ^_^
When you said that $g>0$ is important what do you mean. As I know $g=0$ is a valid condition while considering taking CDF and you also have considered this.

Comment: A density is defined on the whole real line.  This particular one happens to be given by the formula above for $g > 0$ but $0$ for $g \le 0$.  The value at $g=0$ is not important, but it is important to not use your formula when $g < 0$.